# change text-view value automatically on list-view inside buttons click

Tags: android, listview

I have `listView` with two `textView` and one `button`. `onClick` of `button` I want to change value of `textView` automatically.I have a `arrayList` which have stored only one of the `textView` value stored in it,not stored value for another `textView`. I got position of button click but don't know how to change value of `textView` automatically. please help me through this. I see a lot of another answers but couldn't find the solution.

---

`textview1` | `button` | `textview2`
              |
              *

### `button1`|`button2`

This is the format. `onclick` of `button` ,it will show two more buttons `button1` and `button2`. if I choose `button1` then it will change `button` value to 2, and  `textview2` value of that row 20 automatically.If i choose `button2` then it will change `button` value to 5 and `textview2` value to 50.

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: question is not clear, add some code with proper problem description.

Comment: you have to create custom class with required properties and set that class arraylist to adapter so you can manage all values in your listview

Comment: @ShuchiSheth Make one Custom class like with `tv1Value`,`tv2Value`,`btnValue`,`btnVisibility` and First time set default like "","",buttn,false. Then in adapter on click listener of Button, btn1 and btn2 change value as you need and then `notifydatasetchanged()`. So it will reflect. Try this. And are you using ViewHolder class?

Answer (score 0):

> onclick of button ,it will show two more buttons button1 and button2

To make the two button visible, you can do this

- When button clicked, make the two buttons visible

  ```
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v) {
        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
   });
  ```

> if I choose button1 then it will change button value to 2

- When button1 clicked

  ```
  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setText("2");
       }
   });
  ```

Comment: I already set my value on button but not able to change textview value automatically according to the button value

Comment: what value should have in textView ? row 20 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

Make one Model(Custom) java class like **DataModel.java** :-

```
public class DataModel {
String tv1Value, tv2Value, btnValue;
boolean btnsVisibility;

public String getTv1Value() {
    return tv1Value;
}

public void setTv1Value(String tv1Value) {
    this.tv1Value = tv1Value;
}

public String getTv2Value() {
    return tv2Value;
}

public void setTv2Value(String tv2Value) {
    this.tv2Value = tv2Value;
}

public String getBtnValue() {
    return btnValue;
}

public void setBtnValue(String btnValue) {
    this.btnValue = btnValue;
}

public boolean isBtnsVisibility() {
    return btnsVisibility;
}

public void setBtnsVisibility(boolean btnsVisibility) {
    this.btnsVisibility = btnsVisibility;
}
}
```

Then in adapter make code like below:-

1) First of get define `ArrayList<DataModel> datamodels;` variable and get that array-list value in constructor.

2) Add below coding in `getView()` of adapter:-

**Updated**

```
    holder.button.setTag(position);
    holder.button1.setTag(position);
    holder.button2.setTag(position);

    DataModel dataModel = datamodels.get(position);
    holder.button.setText(dataModel.getBtnValue());
    holder.textview2.setText(dataModel.getTv2Value());
    if(dataModel.isBtnsVisibility()) {
        holder.button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        holder.button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (int) v.getTag();
            DataModel singleDataModel = datamodels.get(pos);
            singleDataModel.setBtnsVisibility(true);
            datamodels.set(pos,singleDataModel);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (int) v.getTag();
            DataModel singleDataModel = datamodels.get(pos);
            singleDataModel.setBtnValue("2");
            singleDataModel.setTv2Value("20");
            datamodels.set(pos,singleDataModel);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    holder.button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (int) v.getTag();
            DataModel singleDataModel = datamodels.get(pos);
            singleDataModel.setBtnValue("5");
            singleDataModel.setTv2Value("50");
            datamodels.set(pos,singleDataModel);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```